# Exibir posts do wordpress por categoria

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Uso o código abaixo para exibir os posts da categoria de **ID 1**, porém, ao invés de usar o **ID** da categoria, gostaria de usar o **slug** EX: cat=noticias

```
<?php query_posts('cat=1'); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/), acredito que isso resolva seu problema:

```
query_posts( array(
    'category_name'  => 'my-category-slug',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
) );
```