# Listar produtos que contenham classe de entrega wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Olá pessoal muito boa noite a todos sou novato em wordpress e estou com uma dificuldade para listar produtos em que contenham um classe de entrega a eles.
Por exemplo: tenho uma uma página aonde só sera exibido os produtos que contenham a classe de entrega [fret-gratis] gostaria de saber se isso é possível e quais seria os passos, aguardo respostas obrigado a todos.

Comment: Não seria algo deste gênero? [Exibir posts do wordpress por categoria](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180234/11886)

Comment: O que é uma "classe de entrega"?

Comment: @RicardoMoraleida Classe de entrega seria uma extensão do plugin WooCommerce aonde eu posso setar os produtos que terão Frete Grátis, o que eu quero é listar todos estes produtos que foram setados com a classe frete-gratis  em uma página.